# How to pass a variable to the HTTP request in API call?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
URL='http://localhost:7474/db/neo4j/tx'
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8','Content-Type':'application/json'}

def get_nodes(label, limit_count=50)
  data = {
    "statements" : [ 
        {
          "statement" : "MATCH (n:$label) RETURN n.name LIMIT $nproduct",
          "parameters" : { "nproduct" : $limit_count } 
        } ]
  }
  r = requests.post(URL, headers = headers,json=data)
  r.json()['results'][0]['data']
```

In this query, I intend to query all nodes of a label, i.e. "Product". In this function, how to pass $label, and $limit_count in this function definition?

The current form doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Parameter are normally used when you want to tweak your query with variable values. Neo4j internally binds the parameter values as values(with quotes if it is a string, as is if it is an integer).

Assuming Python3 and Neo4j 3.

```py
URL='http://localhost:7474/db/neo4j/cypher'
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8','Content-Type':'application/json'}

def get_nodes(label, limit_count=50):
    ## Prepare your query
    query = "MATCH (n:{}) RETURN n.name LIMIT {}".format(label, limit_count) 
    data = {
        "query": query,
        "params": {
         ## Params go here if any
        }
    }
    r = requests.post(URL, headers=headers, json=data)
    return r.json()
```